# Cannot connect to Azure VM with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-network

I cannot get my Azure VM with SQL Server to connect from anything other than the local machine.  This is a Windows VM where I downloaded and installed SQL Server manually.  I am at a loss.

If I RDP to the machine and connect to SQL Server it succeeds.  If I attempt to hit it from any other box on my Virtual Network it will not connect.  I can ping the box and the name resolves to the proper IP address.  Test-NetConnection shows that I cannot connect on port 1433, but I can connect on other ports like 3389.

Here is all I've tried/confirmed thus far.

TCP/IP is enabled in configuration manager and set to listen on port 1433.  Remote access is enabled in configurations.

I added a port 1433 Windows firewall rule for all 3 profiles.

I turned off the Windows firewall for all 3 profiles.

Confirmed both machines are definitely on the same virtual network.

The default NSG rule is in place for any port/protocol on the same Virtual Network.

I added an explicit NSG rule for the source IP of another machine to any port/protocol.

I modified the rule that allowed me to RDP to the box from my personal IP to include 1433 in addition to 3389.  Test-NetConnection succeeds on 3389 and fails on 1433.

None of these made a difference.

I created a new VM where the machine came pre-installed with SQL Server.  It connects just fine from any other machine on the VirtualNetwork without making any changes to any firewall or NSG rules.

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of SQL Server did you install on that box?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 Standard

Comment: Is it set up to listen to external connections?

Comment: Yes.  TCP/IP is on.  Remote Access is on.  Is there something else to check?

Answer (score 0):

Is SQL listening on the internal address and an allowed connection IP? http://www.mohamedmostafa.co.uk/blog/2009/10/10/setup-configure-microsoft-sql-server-to-allow-remote-connection-remote-sql-management-studio-access/

Comment: Yes.  Remote Access is enabled and TCP/IP is enabled for the internal IP.

Comment: Has your VM got a public IP, can you access via this? You may need to edit the NSG. Also, Can you telnet to port 1433 via internal address?

Comment: Did you follow the steps in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/announcing-new-azure-vm-images-sql-server-2017-on-linux-and-windows/)? This will also show you how to [modify the set up once provisioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect#connect-to-sql-server-within-a-virtual-network)

Comment: The SQL Configuration option does not appear in the Azure portal for a VM that has SQL Server manually installed.  The VM that followed the steps from that link and had SQL Server pre-installed worked as expected.

Comment: Can you run `netstate -ano | find /i “PIDNumberofSQL-Server”` Where PID is the Process ID of the SQL Service (you can see the in SQL Server Config Manager under SQL Server Services) - [reference](https://imron.com/support/knowledgebase/configuring-a-sql-server-for-remote-connections/)

Comment: TCP    10.0.0.99:1433         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6440
TCP    10.0.0.99:1433         10.0.0.11:58355        ESTABLISHED     6440

Comment: Have you followed all steps in [this article](https://imron.com/support/knowledgebase/configuring-a-sql-server-for-remote-connections/)

Comment: The VM does have a public IP.  I cannot connect via that IP.  I didn't use telnet, but Test-NetConnection reported a failure even after I explicitly opened port 1433.  The other explicitly opened public port, 3389, did pass a Test-NetConnection.

Comment: Yes to most recent link.

Comment: What error do you get when connecting through SSMS? Can you modify your question to show NSG config and SQL remote configuration? Hard to investigate further without more detail

Comment: Your netstate output shows a connection from 10.0.0.11 is this the VM you are connecting from? Are you just doing Test-NetConnection or actually trying to access (if so, what error?)

Answer (score 0):

Sound like your MSSQL is setup with a dynamic port in the tcp/ip protocol. Check the TCP/IP protocol and if the port is blank, set it to the desired port (1433) and set NSG to allow communication on this port.